# django modeltranslation doesn't work with such queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm new to programming.

In my blog I want to show a list of categories.
If I create a queryset like this:

```
Category.objects.all()
```

my django-modeltranslation works perfectly.

But I want to get categories of only published posts. Then my queryset is:

```
Post.objects.values('category__name').filter(is_published=True)
```

However, django-modeltranslation doesn't work. I get values from 'name' field instead 'name_en' or 'name_ru'  fields.

What is wrong?

Here's my models.py :

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=160, unique=True)


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField('title', max_length=150)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='posts', blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you better query in reverse: with `.values(…)` you select a specific database column, so this will omit the model logic.

You can retrieve the categories with:

```
Category.objects.filter(posts__is_published=True).distinct()
```

Comment: You are right. Thank you so much